# Memory Management in objective C Specifically in using Arrays,Objects,Dictionary etc

Tags: memory-management, nsmutablearray

I am very confused with the memory management in objective c.I know that the retain count is incremented when we alloc an object, and that object is released when we call release method. if the retain count become zero then only the memory is free.

But I am not sure about how we use this in the programming especially when memory management of arrays, dictionaries, NSString objects and NSObject objects etc. Anyone please help me with some examples.
I had a question regarding this.
I created an object of type AClass;

```
          AClass * a = [[AClass alloc]init];
```

I add that object into two arrays like

```
        [Arry1 addObject:a]; 
        [Arry2 addObject:a];
```

I am assigning a to another object using copy.

```
        AClass * c = [a copy];
```

How I release c without any memory leak.
Assume AClass contains an arry with some objects like AClassArray.
How I release these AClassArray when I release AClass object a or c.

Any help is appreciable
Thanks

Comment: I strongly suggest that you use ARC (automatic reference counting). This will eliminate most of the memory management problems of Obj-C. With ARC, the compiler inserts all retain, release, and autorelease calls for you.

Comment: I need to know about the memory management eventhough I am using ARC

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but let’s try:

```
AClass * a = [[AClass alloc]init]; // a has now a retain count of 1.  
[a addObject:AClassArray]; // Adding an object to an array increases its retain count. Thus a has still a retain count of 1, and the retain count of AClassArray is increased by 1.  
[Arry1 addObject:a]; // a has now a retain count of 2.  
[Arry2 addObject:a]; // a has now a retain count of 3.

AClass * c = [a copy]; // copy creates a new object. Thus c has a retain count of 1, and a still has a retain count of 3.
```

If now `a` or `c` is released, the object gets a `dealloc` message. In this method, one has to release all `ivars` of the object. So if `a` and `c` have a retained property which is an array `AClassArray`  containing some objects, `AClassArray` has to be sent a `release` message in `dealloc` of `a` and `c`. `AClassArray` then sends a `release` message to all objects it contains.

A more detailed description can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW12).
But as I said before in my comment, all this is handled automatically by using ARC.

Comment: Thank you for your concern. One thing i need a clarification. If i need to call release to object a, i need to call three times for release the object a. Isn't it?

Comment: In the example above, "a" has 3 owners: The object "x" that initialized "a", and "Arry1" and "Arry2". Thus "a" has to be released 3 times, right. "x" does it by calling release on "a", and an "a" stored in an array gets a release either when it is removed from the array, or when the array itself is released (because then all of its stored objects get a release).